# Import Flask Issue with Python File

Tags: python

When I run the file below I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/msk/bssproject/sendmail.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
ImportError: No module named flask
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

I have confirmed that Flask is properly installed, so it is not that I haven't installed flask.

Here is the file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
import flask.views
from flask.forms import ContactForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail

mail = Mail()

app = Flask(__name__)

mail.init_app(app)

app.config.update( 
    DEBUG = True, 
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    MAIL_PORT = 465, 
    MAIL_USE_TLS = False, 
    MAIL_USE_SSL = True, 
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'usernname@gmail.com', 
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'password%')

mail = Mail(app)

def send_email():
    form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            flash('All fields are required')
        return render_template('feedback.html', form=form)
    else:
        msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='mlkrgr@gmail.com', recipients=['mlkrgr@gmail.com'])
        msg.body = "feedback.html"      
        send (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
        mail.send(msg)
    return 'Form posted'

class Submit(flask.views.MethodView):
    def post(self):
        send_email()
        return flask.render_template('thanks.html')

app.add_url_rule('/',
        view_func=Submit.as_view('submit'),
        methods=["POST"])

app.run()
```

Comment: If you open up a Python console, does `import flask` work?

Comment: Thanks. When I give the command import flask in the Python console, it does not do anything and a new blank line with >>> appears.

Comment: You say that you've "installed flask", but realize that there are multiple ways to "install" a Python library, and then multiple ways to "run" Python to use those libraries. If you use `import sys; print sys.path` you can see the directories where Python is looking to find your libraries. You may find that how you run python will differ where it is looking.

Comment: If you use a virtualenv for your app development you may want to add a shebang at the beginning of your python code to make sure you are using the correct instance of python (and its libraries). Example: `#!/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python`.